# Error with filemd5 filepath using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have such problem with Terraform:
I need to create archive (I use **data.archive_file** with **output_path = ./archive/s3/my_test_archive.zip**) and then I wanna upload archive to aws bucket (using aws_s3_object).
To check hash sum I use

> `etag = filemd5("${data.archive_file.my_archive.output_path}")`

But when I run `terraform apply` I get error

> ````
>   on module\main.tf line 20, in resource "aws_s3_object" "object":
>   :   etag   = filemd5("${data.archive_file.my_archive.output_path}") 
>     ├────────────────
>     │ while calling filemd5(path)
>     │ data.archive_file.my_archive.output_path is "./archive/s3/my_test_archive.zip"
> │ Call to function "filemd5" failed: open archive/s3/my_test_archive.zip: The > system cannot find the file specified..```
> ````

I guess it's cause when Terraform is checking the code at the same moment file doesn't exist.

If I disable etag check this will work, but I need to check changes in archive.
How can I resolve it?

Comment: You can create an empty zip file prior to running plan and apply.

Comment: What is the full code producing the error?

Comment: ```data "archive_file" "my_archive" {
 type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "./files/to_s3/"
  output_path = "./archive/s3/${resource.random_id.my_random_id.id}.zip" }```



```resource "aws_s3_object" "object" {
  bucket      = var.bucket_name
  key         = "${resource.random_id.my_random_id.id}.zip"
  source      = "./archive/s3/my_test_archive.zip"
  etag          = filemd5 ("${data.archive_file.my_archive.output_path}") 
}```

Comment: in this code Im using random_id as name for archive

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this. `terraform plan` has worked & I see `filemd5` output. I don't expect `aws_s3_object` to fail unless it bypasses the dependency on `data.archive_file.my_archive.output_path` & runs ahead. By any chance you have access problems to `archive` directory or `symlinks` or failing on CI apps like Jenkins?

Comment: @harshavmb I found a reason why its not reproduce. I have dependency at **data "archive_file**. It seems **depends_on  = [resource.local_file.compose_file]**
In **resource.local_file.compose_file** above I fill templatefile that I want to add to archive

Comment: I noticed this step **resource "aws_s3_object"** runs before needed step **data "archive_file"**. Although, there are pointer   **depends_on = [data.archive_file.my_archive]**. It seems it doesnt work

Comment: Logs: 
`module.rev-11.random_id.my_random_id: Refreshing state...
module.rev-11.local_file.dest["docker-compose.yml"]: Refreshing state... 
module.rev-11.local_file.dest["elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml"]: Refreshing state... 
module.rev-11.local_file.compose_file: Refreshing state... 
module.rev-11.aws_s3_object.object: Refreshing state...
│ Error: Error in function call
│   on revision\main.tf line 88, in resource "aws_s3_object" "object": ...`